# How to display number of correct answers?

Tags: c, while-loop

I am beginning programming C and have came up with a short quiz program. the program asks the user to enter the number of questions they want to answer. then the questions are in the same format (# + # + # - #) but random numbers are generated each time. My question is how to i display to the user the number of correct answers they have gotten at the end of the program? i know you will have to execute a print f statement to display it but i don't know what else

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{

srand(time(NULL));

int NumQuestions = 0;
int responce = 0;
int loopcount = 0;
int answer = 0;
int NumCorrect = 0; // HOW TO GET THIS ???????????????????????????????

printf("\n\welcome to your math quize!\n ");

printf("\ntype the numer of questions you would like to answer: ");
scanf("%d", &NumQuestions); //number of questions. 

while(loopcount<NumQuestions){

int n1 = 0;
int n2 = 0; 
int n3 = 0; 
int n4 = 0;
n1 = rand()% 9 + 1;
n2 = rand()% 9 + 1; 
n3 = rand()% 9 + 1; 
n4 = rand()% 9 + 1; 
answer = n1 + n2 + n3 - n4;

              printf("\n%d + %d + %d - %d =", n1, n2, n3, n4);
              scanf("%d", &responce); // user answer

                          if(responce == answer)
                           printf("\ncorrect\n");

                           else
                           printf("\nincorrect\n");

loopcount++;
} //exit loop

printf("you got %d andswers correct!", NumCorrect); //????????????????????????????

getch();
} // end process
```

Answer (score 1):

In your if-statement here:

```
 if(responce == answer)
                       printf("\ncorrect\n");

                       else
                       printf("\nincorrect\n");
```

You should first add braces and properly format it:

```
 if (responce == answer) {
     printf("\ncorrect\n");
 } else {
     printf("\nincorrect\n");
 }
```

Then you should fix the English:

```
 if (response == answer) {
     printf("\ncorrect\n");
 } else {
     printf("\nincorrect\n");
 }
```

And then all you need to do is increment the counter for the correct case:

```
 if (response == answer) {
     printf("\ncorrect\n");
     correct_count++;
 } else {
     printf("\nincorrect\n");
 }
```

Also, note that I used `correct_count` here instead of `NumCorrect`, because you should be consistent in your naming; all your other variables are lower case, so why did you choose to make `NumCorrect` title cased? Consistency is incredibly important as part of regular programming discipline.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(responce == answer){
         printf("\ncorrect\n");
         NumCorrect ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable called `NumCorrect`, but you are not using it inside your `while` loop.

You need to be doing something to it inside the `while` loop, perhaps inside the `if` statement. ;-)